# How to pull an item in an array into another array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I need to pull a value from an array into another array, but it's not working. 
I have a document **Company**:

```
{
   _id: String,
   companyName: String,
   address: String,
   employees: [Employee],
   ...
}
```

**Employee**:

```
{
   idRegister: String,
   employeeName: String,
   markers: [Marker],
   ...
}
```

**Marker**:

```
{
   tag: String
   ...
}
```

So I tried the query:

```
db.company.update(
{
   $and: 
     [
           {
              _id: "8qmypja88nbuoedsi"
           }, 

           {
             'employee.idRegister': "567.567"

           }
      ]
  }, 

  {
       $pull:
           {
             'employees.markers.tag': 
              {
                 $elemMach: 
                 {
                   "ghj-5675"
                 }
               }
            }
     }});
```

But I got the error:

```
"writeError" : {
     "code" : 2,
     "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $elemMatch"
}
```

Anyone knows how can I pull a specific tag? I've tried another queries without $elemMatch before I write here, but no success either.

Answer (score 0):

from [mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
{ $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] }, vegetables: "carrots" } },
```

so in your case

```
$pull:{ 'employees.markers':{"tag":"ghj-5675"}}
```

Comment: `db.company.update({$elemMatch: {$eq: {'employees.idRegister': "567.567"}}}, {$pull:{'employees.markers': {"tag": "ghj-5675"}}});`


With this command I got these error:


`WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 2,
                "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $elemMatch"
        }
})`

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!

I should specify the array item which the update would be made, so I did:

```
db.company.update({"_id" : "8qmypja88nbuoedsi", 'employees.idRegister': "567.567"}, 
   {
     $pull:
        {
          'employees.$.markers': 
           {
             $in:
                 [ 
                   {tag: "ghj-5675"}
                 ]
           }
         }
   });
```

Thanks for the help @profesor79